# Setting custom windows background color in Windows 8.1 doesn't work

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I am using Windows 8.1 and I understand that I can no longer set a custom windows background color through the UI (as you could in Windows 7). But there is this registry key:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors -> Window

I'm supposed to be able to change the RGB value in that key as needed. So I changed it to my bgcolor of choice, rebooted, and I still have white windows everywhere. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What makes you think that changing that setting would work in 8.1?

Comment: When you say "windows background color" it might sound like you're talking about the desktop background color, but am I right to say that you're actually referring to application window colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Windows 8.0, colors are NOT changeable like they used to be. (Active Title, Inactive Title, Window Text, Window, Control Text, Control, ...)

So the change you did has no effect.

If you need custom window color due to health issues so you are OK with some spartan appearence, then switch your color scheme to **High Contrast** and customize the colors there. Unlike in normal color schemes, colors in **High Contrast** are completely customizable and Windows obeys them. On the other hand, visual user experience is limited.

Once you have selected **High Contrast** color scheme, you can switch to normal and back using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>.

How to customize colors in High Contrast:

1. Switch to desired High Contrast mode (colors must change)
2. Click **Color** link below the list:
   [image]

To prevent eye problems caused by high contrast I strongly recommend to decrease default color contrast by adding some grey (and adjusting other colors accordingly). Here's what I mean:

[image]

- there is one additional color you can set: desktop background color. To change it, click **Desktop Background** link visible on the first image.

Comment: I tried High Contrast and discovered that those colors are not customizable, even with registry hacks. Windows 8.x is horrible.

Comment: That looks interesting and I'll try. But help me understand why MS doesn't simply make the colors customizable without first jumping through the hoop of high contrast. It's a feature that's been in windows all the way back to Win2K and maybe even windows 95. They remove important features and add stupid ones.

Comment: @SweatCoder – please check [how color settings work in Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3380-color-appearance-change-windows-10-a.html). You can see that trend is about choosing single dominant color and other colors will accomodate accordingly. Old registry settings seem to be present only for backward application compatibility so apps can read/write them but the look goes its own way, ignoring them. You can see design approach dominating over technical one. But Windows only follows latest trends in consumer user interfaces visible also on other platforms outside the Microsoft.

Comment: miroxlav, I got the color customization to work, as you described above. Pretty cool except for 1 thing: the default background color of all non-window backgrounds is still black. How can I change that? For example, the windows desktop, taskbar background, other misc things, all black background. If I can change this default black to something else it would be legit. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Takbar background, scrollbars and other areas are colored by **Button Background** color. On the last image in the above answer, the color is black. Try to change it to something else. Desktop color is controlled by **Desktop Background** link you can see left of **Color** link you clicked (see the first image in the answer). Most of things (except Metro app tiles) is now colored as you expect. FYI you can read [how a Windows app should be designed to work with standard colors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848048(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the only way for those registry settings to have effect (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors -> Window) is to install **UXTheme Patcher**. Once installed, those colors get invoked, though inconsistently. Some windows (like Notepad) appear with the custom color background, while others (such as Windows Explorer) remains stark white. And sometimes even the colored windows revert to white randomly and won't go back to custom until after a reboot.

Unbelievable how sucky windows 8.x is.

Comment: **Important:** This approach performs replacing UI rendering libraries. This can affect system stability and reliability and is not recommended from security viewpoint. Change these Windows core libraries solely at your own risk.