# How to Changing Windows 8.1' elements colors to get better visualization?

Tags: windows-8.1, colors

A photo is worth a thousand words:
[image]

This is a Windows Explorer's file listing detail view. I can't view the end of each column because the line is almost invisible in my notebook. 
Since I'm a developer, in my own programs I changed that color to a darker gray and my eyes (and the customer's) thanked.

Where I can find the app to change those Windows default colors to something less eye demanding?

NOTE: I would like if it is possible with bare Windows, but 3rd party apps are ok.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting custom windows background color in Windows 8.1 doesn't work](http://superuser.com/questions/929095/setting-custom-windows-background-color-in-windows-8-1-doesnt-work)

Comment: Font on sample you provided is rendered poorly. Do you think you can enable ClearType and then run its tuning wizard?

Comment: @miroxlav Good tip. Not directly related with main problem, but thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oficially, the only way you have is to [switch to High Contrast themes](https://superuser.com/questions/929095/setting-custom-windows-background-color-in-windows-8-1-doesnt-work) and there you can tweak all colors. On the other hand, Windows will not render background images on many places, including web pages.

Unoficially, you can search for "Windows 8.1 Skins" or "Windows 8.1 Themes" and you will find 3rd-party software which can change Windows user interface including its colors. But since Windows look is rendered by core DLL libraries, this 3rd-party software overwrites them, so technically, it is "damaging" your Windows installation. Do it on your risk, I do not endorse this in any way. I am also a sofware developer and I don't want to risk unwanted side effects on my main PC.

Also improve your font display, because you agree that part of the problem is font rendering. Most likely the ClearType is turned off in your computer. Re-enable it and run its tuning wizard to fine-tune it for your screen.

---

EDIT: After OP's comment, I've made some research regarding Windows Blinds and [found](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/244384-faq-windowblinds-vs-style-xp-vs-uxtheme/) that Windows Blinds should be able to modify themes without patching uxtheme.dll file. So it looks like an option, too, although it is not a free software.

Comment: @#$&%$&# Microsoft....

Comment: I'll use WindowBlinds, which appear to act without substituing system dlls.

Comment: @FabricioAraujo – you are right, I found some analysis of technology published by their developer. Answer updated. Also, do not swear at Microsoft's account. Why do you think that companies will allow you to skin their software, if its look is part of their brand? [The same](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/256) for Apple's OS X. (Not even mentioning mobile operating systems.) If you were their CEO, would you make their OS skinnable? Really?

Comment: "because you are complaining about poor readability". I'm complaining about difficult about graphic elements like column headers, the font was part of it but not the main problem.
Being able to skin the SO in a situation like that is similar to drink water on the desert. " If you were their CEO, would you make their OS skinnable? " YEAH. It's the user computer after all, so it MUST be able to change the elements of screen to their comfort.